# How to find user SID in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, sid

I am using objective-c for the first time.

My requirement is to authenticate the logged in user and find their SID.

In windows development we have a very few APIS, with the help of which we can find out the SID of the user.

My assumption is: there should be some functions in the cocoa framework which should tell us the SID of the user.

If there is no such feature, then how else should I try to find it?

Guide me on this.

Comment: For the non windows users here: What is a SID?

Comment: The [SID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Identifier) seems to be a Windows-only thing.

Comment: Yes I agree with you.But I have one use case where mac machine is added to windows domain. So for this user there should be some unique identity in domain controller.Please help to find it and also let me know if some other terminology is available for mac users.Thanks, Tausif.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a unique identifier for the device.

This open source project helps you get that:

[UIDevice-with-UniqueIdentifier-for-iOS-5](https://github.com/gekitz/UIDevice-with-UniqueIdentifier-for-iOS-5)

From the documentation:

> use `[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueDeviceIdentifier]` to retrieve the
>   unique identifier (it's a hash of your Bundle ID + MAC address)
>
> use `[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueGlobalDeviceIdentifier]` to
>   retrieve a global unique identifier (it's a hash of the MAC address,
>   used for tracking between different apps).

Comment: In windows SID is unique identity of the domain user.But what will happen if the mac machine is added to windows active directory? Fot this user there should be some unique identity in domain controller which can be used while authenticating any user. Please let me know what is that in mac and how to find it.Thanks , Tausif.